# How can I create a vmware disk with XEN?

Tags: linux, virtualization, vmware-esx, xen, sles10

I found that in XEN I can use vmware-disk images.
But can I actually create such a disk with pure XEN-means?

I want to create a server with XEN and move the corresponding disk later to VMWARE (in a simple case this is just a data disk).

I currently run XEN that comes with SLES10 SP4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**qemu-img** is part of the virt-utils. They are part of SLES11...

You can also use "[VMware Converter](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1005298)" to convert your xen disk to vmware format.

Comment: Also found the qemu tool, which is capable for converting xen images to vmware compatible format.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/qemu-img

Comment: Typically you use plain raw images/volumes with Xen thus any tool (such as the ones mentioned above) which supports vmware format will do. I would try `qemu-img` also first.

Comment: VMWare Converter sounds complicated - and seems to run only with windows, if I correctly understood the KB-article from vmware. virt-utils from sles10 should contain qemu-img?

Comment: Yes, virt-utils package seems to contain qemu-img binary.